# changing id attribute on runtime jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a submit button with id=submit that i used to save new record.

```
// Add new customer
                $("#submit").click(function() {
                    var data = $.param($("#form").serializeArray());
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "crudcustomers.php",
                        data: data,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            $("#message").attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
                            $("#message").html(msg);
                            // Rebind datagrid after record added.
                            getRecords();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Now when i came to update an existing record i simple populate the existing record into form fields and on run time i change the id=submit to id=update. see below.

```
 success: function(response) {
                            /*console.log(response);*/
                            // Taking ajax response into javascript objects to fill the form fields
                            object = $.parseJSON(response);
                            $("#customername").attr('value', object[0].name);
                            $("#customercnic").attr('value', object[0].cnic);
                            $("#customeraddress").attr('value', object[0].address);
                            $("#customeremail").attr('value', object[0].email);
                            $("#customerphone").attr('value', object[0].phone);
                            $("#submit").attr('id','update'); // i change the attr here 
                        }
```

Now i am trying to run a function

```
  // Update customers
                $("#update").click(function(){
                    alert("working");
                });
```

But instead of running the alert function the #update.click is also running my saving record function..I tried placing it outside the document.ready but didn't work

Please help me Thanks.

Comment: Changing the ID of an element will not remove any event handlers already assigned to it.  Use `.off()` to remove the event handler, as well as assigning the new handler.

Comment: Why not create two buttons and show one of them at a time?

Comment: @SalmanA that can be an option too lets see if this can be solved, else i will try your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use delegation, e.g:

```
$(document).on('click','#update',function(){...});
```

And the same for submit:

```
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){...});
```

*document should be replaced by closest static container*

That's said, switching element ID is never a good idea AFAIK

Comment: Thank you i used delegation. i think i should get the concept of delegation . any ways thank you it worked )

Answer (score 1):

When you change the ID you should also unbind the event handler like so:

```
$("#submit").attr('id','update').off('click');
```

[jQuery Off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: I replaced the code with yours, although it stopped the old function to execute means it unbind the existing event. But it is also not running the new function i attach with click

Comment: @Raheel When do you bind the click event onto the #update element? Is it after you change the ID?

Comment: yes on when user click the edit link i change the button id from #submit to #update... then i made a function #update.click...

Comment: okay i used your .off method and then used delegation event. its working now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case you've changed the elements id, but you did not change the events attached to the DOM object.

for example, you have a DOM object Form with id=submit and event click(function1(){}).

When you change the id of the element, you have a DOM object Form with id=update and event click(function1(){}, and function2(){}).

edit:
 You should use: $( "#submit").unbind( "click" ); OR $( "#update").unbind( "click" );

Comment: the detach does not remove events Definition and Usage
The detach() method removes the selected elements, including all text and child nodes. However, it keeps data and events.??

Comment: my bad, try this: $( "#submit").unbind( "click" );

OR $( "#update").unbind( "click" );

Comment: lol the off was atleast stopping the #submit.click to work ...the unbind do not even stop :D